# C# reflection and instantiation - is there a way to do Activator.CreateInstance(myType){ X = x }?

Tags: c#, reflection, instantiation

I'm not sure of the terminology for this kind of code, but I want to know if it's possible to instantiate variables after the parentheses, but whilst using reflection.

I have a map which gets loaded from an XML file. This is a collection of (int X, int Y, string S) where the X,Y is the position of some terrain, and S is a string representing the type of the terrain. I have a dictionary to pass between the strings and the relevant types; for example one key-value pair might be "Tree", typeof(Tree).

When using reflection, although I know it's possible to instantiate with parameters, the only way I'm comfortable is just by using Activator.CreateInstance(Type t), i.e. with an empty constructor.

When I had the maps hard coded, I would originally instantiate like this (within some i,j for loop):

```
case: "Tree"
 world.Add( new Tree(i,j) );
```

Whilst starting to think about reflection and my save file, I changed this to:

```
world.Add( new Tree() { X = i, Y = j }
```

However, I realised that this won't work with reflection, so I am having to do the following (Tree inherits from Terrain, and the dictionary just converts the XML save data string to a type):

```
Type type = dictionary[dataItem.typeAsString];
Terrain t = (Terrain)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
t.X = i;
t.Y = j;
world.Add(t);
```

I would prefer to do this using something like

```
Type type = dictionary[dataItem.typeAsString];
world.Add((Terrain)Activator.CreateInstance(type) { X = i, Y = j }
```

Is there any shortcut like this? I guess if not I could edit world.Add to take an X and Y and cast to Terrain in there to access those variables, but I am still curious as to a) what this {var1 = X, var2 = Y} programming is called, and b) whether something similar exists when using reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is called Object Initializer syntax and is just syntactic sugar for setting the properties.

The code `var result = new MyType { X = x }` will be compiled to this:

```
MyType __tmp = new MyType();
__tmp.X = x;
MyType result = __tmp;
```

You will have to do that yourself using `PropertyInfo.SetValue` if you know the instantiated type only at runtime or use the normal property setters if the type is known at compile time.

Comment: Is using PropertyInfo.SetValue better than just casting to my base class which I know the type will inherit from? (Terrain)

Comment: @Haighstrom: No, it isn't. Casting to the base type and using the properties defined there is prefered, because it is easier to read, is refactoring safe and performs better.

Comment: OK thanks. In that case I will go down the route of casting and setting variables from within the World.Add function, which perhaps I need to set up several overloads for. Alternatively I could just bite the bullet and use reflection with parameters, as per Zarathos' answer below.

Comment: @Haighstrom: Yes, both approaches work. It actually depends on how you want to model your classes. Using `Zarathos` approach would mean that every derived class that could possibly be instantiated via this method needs to have a constructor that requires exactly the parameters of the properties on the base type. Not more, not less.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, good point. Maybe casting is better then, as I can't be sure at this stage of my class structure/constructors later on (but I can be sure than that Terrain will always hold the X and Y)

Comment: @Haighstrom: Yes, casting is definitly the less fragile approach here.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, because the [object initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you mention (introduced with LINQ in 3.0) is an illusion of the compiler.  As in, when you type this

```
var foo = new Foo { Bar = "baz" };
```

the compiler actually converts it into CLS-compliant IL which equates to

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = "baz";
```

Phil Haack has a [great blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/11/hidden-pitfalls-with-object-initializers.aspx) which not only covers the details of this rewriting done by the compiler, but also some side effects it can cause when dealing with types that implement `IDisposable`

As all of this is nothing but a feint by the compiler, there is no equivalent using reflection (i.e., `Activator.CreateInstance(Type t)`).  Others will give you workarounds, but in the end there really is no direct equivalent.

Probably the closest generic hack you could manage would be to create a method that accepted an object, then used reflection in order to identify the properties of that object and their respective values in order to perform object initialization for you.  It might be used something like this

```
var foo = Supercollider.Initialize<Foo>(new { Bar = "baz" });
```

and the code would be something like (this is off the top of my head)

```
public sealed class Supercollider
{    
    public static T Initialize<T>(object propertySource)
    {
        // you can provide overloads for types that don't have a default ctor
        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)); 
        foreach(var prop in ReflectionHelper.GetProperties(typeof(T)))
            ReflectionHelper.SetPropertyValue(
                result, // the target
                prop,  // the PropertyInfo 
                propertySource); // where we get the value
    }    
}
```

You'd have to get each property from the anonymous object, find a property in your target type with the same exact name and type, then get the value from that property in the anonymous object and set the value of your target's property to this value.  Its not incredibly hard, but its absolutely prone to runtime exceptions and issues where the compiler chooses a different type for the anonymous type's property, requiring you be more specific (e.g., `new { Bar = (string)null }`), which screws with the elegance of the thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2, ...);
```

As described [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx).

Comment: this is not field/property initialization, but passing parameters to constructors..

Comment: But the OP HAS the two argument constructor (note the `new Tree(i,j)`!

Comment: It's far better to build another constructor and Invoke it if you have only few params.

Comment: true! I've not read carefully. I got the impression that OP wants the init-syntax (the {X=1}), but he actually wants to quickly initialize, and asks how-to.

Comment: yes, this doesn't answer exactly what I asked, but it is very helpful and provides an alternative route... (i.e. it looks like instantiating non-empty constructors with reflection doesn't look so hard after all). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public sealed class ReflectionUtils
    {

        public static T ObjectInitializer<T>(Action<T> initialize)
        {
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            initialize(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

public class MyModel
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And after that just make the call :

```
var myModel = ReflectionUtils.ObjectInitializer<MyModel>(m => 
   {
     m.Name = "Asdf"
   });
```

The advantage is that in this way you will have type safety and use reflection as minimum required, because we all know that reflection is an expensive operation that should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a constructor which takes those arguments, then use

[`Activator.CreateInstance(type, i, j)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)

But you won't be able to use the object initialization syntax. Which is just sugar candy for setting the properties.